# Login - Does not want to redirect

Tags: php

**SOLVED: There was a stupid mistake which caused this problem. In header.php i wrote $_SESSION["header"] (which doesnt even exist) instead of $_SESSION["logged"]. Thanks to everyone for your help.**

Login.php does not want to redirect after i enter correct login information.

The page just refreshes and clears the input fields.

(Also the session is created in /tmp folder )

Does anyone have any ideas? :S

Thanks in advance! :)

**login.php:**

```
<?php

$message = NULL;

if (isset($_POST["enter"])) {

    include 'cred.php';
    $newUser = $_POST["user"];
    $newPass = md5($_POST["pass"]);

  if ($newUser==$user AND $newPass==$pass) {

    session_start();
    $_SESSION["logged"]=1;
    $_SESSION["user"]=$newUser;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;

  } else {

    $message = 'failure';

  }

}



?>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body {

    margin-top:120px;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Uporabnik:<br /> <input type="text" name="user" /><br /><br />
Geslo:<br /> <input type="password" name="pass" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="enter"/><br /><br />
<?php if($message!=NULL) {echo $message;} ?>
</form>
</center>
</body>
```

**cred.php:**

```
<?php

$user = 'janeznovak';
$pass= md5('greek123');

?>
```

**EDIT :** Added the header.php file, which is part of every (index.php, second.php, third.php) page. Maybe the problem lies here:

```
<?php

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION["header"])OR $_SESSION["header"]!=1){

    header('Location: login.php');
    exit;


} else {

    $nuser = $_SESSION["user"];
}


?>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<a href="index.php">Prva</a> | 
<a href="second.php">Druga</a> | 
<a href="third.php">Tretja</a> | 
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a> | 
Prijavljeni ste kot <?php echo $nuser; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: session is created in /tmp folder , can you please clarify this

Comment: also mention the error if you got??

Comment: I use WAMP. Session is succesfuly created and stored to /tmp folder but page does not want to redirect me to index.php.

Comment: @user6613 where you set `$_SESSION["header"]` after login??

Comment: Well yes, the problem is with the header.php. You're redirecting to login.php every time.

Comment: @Juhana Oh, but of course, there is $_SESSION["header"] (which doesnt event exist) instead of $_SESSION["logged"]. *facepalm*. It works now. Like a charm :)) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add one more session variable on your login.php

```
 session_start();
$_SESSION["logged"]=1;
$_SESSION["header"] = 1;
$_SESSION["user"]=$newUser;
header('Location: index.php');
```

hope now it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try to just use the form with action="" instead of action=""

Also give the input types a ID and add session_start(); after you open php:

Edit: I also don't understand why you use  in the form page while you including header.php which already have  in it.

I also don't see anywhere where you set the session $_SESSION['header'] ?

Also change this:

if(!isset($_SESSION["header"])OR $_SESSION["header"]!=1){

to:

```
if (!isset ($_SESSION['header'])) {

    header("Location: login.php");

} elseif ($_SESSION['header'] != 1) {

    header("Location: login.php");

}
```

Comment: *I also don't see anywhere where you set the session $_SESSION['header'] ?* +1 That was the problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you include cred.php?
Add in login.php at first code line:

```
include("cred.php");
```

Comment: strange. I've reproduced your scripts on my MAMP environment and it works withoud any changes. Try to enable error logging - may be it'll give you an answer. just put error_loging(E_ALL) at the beginning of login.php

Comment: Weird. It shouldnt work, because the problem was a stupid mistake ($_SESSION["header"] instead of $_SESSION["logged"] inside header.php). Check my answer,where I replied to Juhana.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the if statement to check your username and password actually evaluates to true. Instead of doing a redirect there, why dont you debug it by using a print or echo statement.

```
if ($newUser==$user AND $newPass==$pass) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["logged"]=1;
    $_SESSION["user"]=$newUser;
    $message = "success";
  }
```

If the print statement runs, then do as other people have already said and include("cred.php"); at the top of the page, not inside the if statment.